# How to solve infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{2^{(n+1)}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please help me solve an infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{(n+1)}}$$

I put it in Wolfram Alpha and got the result that it converges to $1$

I know that the infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

Converges to $1$.

But my series is quite different as it has an additional $n$ term multiplied in, and I can't quite see how to solve it to arrive at result $1$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the infinite geometric progression
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}.\tag1
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.\tag2
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ by $x^2$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n+1}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}.\tag3
$$
Setting $x=\dfrac12$ to $(3)$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^2}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2}=\large\color{blue}{1}.
$$

Comment: Your DE MAN!!!!!