# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n = ?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n = ?$$

How to find it? If it lacked n before fraction, I would use formula for the sum of geometric series.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854566/how-to-solve-infinite-series-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n1

Answer (score 4):

Consider the infinite geometric progression for $|x|<1$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}.\tag1
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.\tag2
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ by $x$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.\tag3
$$
Setting $x=\dfrac23$ to $(3)$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \left(\frac23\right)^{n}=\frac{\frac23}{\left(1-\frac23\right)^2}=\large\color{blue}{6}.
$$

Comment: (1) is true for $\;|x|<1\;$